# Advantages of a separate thread in C program

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I have a capture program which in addition do capturing data and writing it into a file also prints some statistics.The function that prints the statistics

```
static void report(void)
{
         /*Print statistics*/
}
```

is called roughly every second using an ALARM that expires every second.So The program is like

```
void capture_program()
{


            while()
            {
                     /*Main loop*/
                     if(doreport)
                          report();
            }
}
```

The expiry of the timer sets the `doreport` flag.If this flag is set `report()` is called which clears the flag.

Now my question is

I am planning to move the reporting function to a separate thread.The main motivation to 
do this is that the reporting function executes some code that is under a lock.Now if another process is holding the lock,then this will block causing the capture process to drop packets.So I think it might be a better idea to move the reporting to a thread.

2) If I were to implementing the reporting in a separate thread,should I still have to use
timers inside the thread to do reporting every second?

```
                         OR
```

Is there a better way to do that by making the thread wakeup at every 1 second interval

Comment: What are the disadvantages to keeping things the way they are?  It works, right?  What's the motivation to change it?  Is that while loop constantly spinning and burning cycles?

Comment: @Duck - Please see updated question explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the advantages in moving the reporting function to a separate thread?

If your reporting function is trivial, for example, you just need to print some thing, I don't think a separate thread will help a lot.

> If I were to implementing the reporting in a separate thread, should I still have to use timers inside the thread to do reporting every second?

You don't need timers, you can just go to sleep every second, like this:

```
static void report(void)
{
    while (1) {
        /*Print statistics*/
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will wait more than a second and will drift.  You really need to measure how long report takes and then sleep for 1-x length of time so that it stays on the second.  And something else: http://tdistler.com/2010/06/27/high-performance-timing-on-linux-windows